# Facebook Analytic with Ionic Framework v1

Tags: angularjs, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework, facebook-sdk-4.0

I need to run the facebook analytics on my hybrid application made on Ionic framework. I have created an application in facebook developer console. I want to know the following app events for my application using facebook sdk:

1. List item
2. No of installs from Facebook clicks
3. Logging app activation
4. App Launched
5. Completed registration
6. Rated
7. App invites

Is there any way around to achieve this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am having the exact same thing now.

Comment: Looking for exact requirement , have you found any solution ?

Comment: no havent found any, moved on to next ticket, waiting for someone to post an answer

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be using this plugin https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4, look at the `logEvent` method.

And you will then need to implement custom events (although some of those you mentioned will be tracked by default)

Comment: I am looking for the exact thing but it looks like the plugin you suggested does more than events. Does this plugin require facebook login to track events?

Comment: @KosalaNuwanPerera - From the documentation "App events allow you to understand the makeup of users engaging with your app, measure the performance of your Facebook mobile app ads, and reach specific sets of your users with Facebook mobile app ads."

So yes - I believe your users will be logging in with their facebook credentials, and these will be used in the logging.

Comment: Thanks @IonicBurger. I am asking this because I don't want to prompt users to sign in to facebook and grant permission via my app to use Analytics for Apps. The Facebook Analytics for Apps FAQ says login is optional.
Have you tried using this plugin only for Analytics without prompting users to grant FB permissions?